# Converting character variable (which is numbers) to numeric leading to inflation of numbers

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have a list of numbers between 0.2 and 95 which are coded as character variables when I import from a csv using `readr::read_csv()`. I have tried using the `as.numeric()` function but it inflates all the numbers between 0 and 550. Is there a way to fix this?

I have also tried `as.numeric(as.character(TimeEstimation))`

```
library(tidyverse)

pros_ll <- readr::read_csv("./data/prosp_ll.csv") %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      TimeEstimation = as.numeric(TimeEstimation) 
      )
```

Comment: Can you please supply a minimum reproducible example? So in this case a .csv/link/code to write a .csv, with the numbers you want to convert, and the code you are running to convert them.

Comment: Your update is still not very reproducible. As of now it's impossible to figure out why you say you have values between 0.2 and 95, but your code gives 0 to 550. so once you've imported your csv into R (before running the as.numeric mutate), can you do `head(dput(pros_ll))` and share this code with us?

Comment: Please post the output from `dput(readr::read_csv("./data/prosp_ll.csv"))` (or `dput(head(...))` if the file is large.  Also, note the typo in your code: you're missing a closing quote in `read_csv`.

Comment: you could try `TimeEstimation = as.numeric(factor(TimeEstimation)`